# Angular ngx-charts-bar-vertical-stacked yAxis addition two values

Tags: angular

I want to get a vertical bar chart with swimlane.
But yaxis take the addition of my two values in my data file :

```
var multi = [
  {
    "name": "Test",
    "series": [
      {
        "name": "Takes",
        "value": 10
      },
      {
        "name": "Total",
        "value": 20
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to have in my y axis just my total value for each name is it possible ?

I try this option [yAxisTickFormatting] but with no result ...